# Infopath 2013 - hide fields when 'New' form is filled out, show fields when form is 'Edited'?

Tags: infopath

I have been asked to hide some fields on an InfoPath form when a user selects 'New Item' or 'New Form', but then un hide the fields when the form is opened in 'edit' mode - is this possible and how would I go about doing this?
Also, with the above form, I have been asked to make one field mandatory when a user selects 'New Item' or 'New Form' so that the field is filled in, but when the form is opened in 'edit' mode, the field must not be mandatory - is this possible and how would I go about doing this?

Thank you very much for your time and assistance -

Kind regards,

Janice

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to accomplish this by creating a new view in Infopath. essentially you are creating two separate forms that can function differently and show different fields.

You do this by selecting the Page Design ribbon and then click on the New View option on the left. You can cut and paste your original form into the new view for a quick start on designing it.

Then on your SharePoint page, simply edit the page the Infopath form is on and edit the form web part, you will have the option to select the default view in the properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can also hide the field by wrapping it in a section and put a formatting rule to hide the section with the condition "ID is blank" which will only be true on a new form.  I use this one a lot.